# Reference a filename from another cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following formula at the moment, where **22May UoE Weight Data ECC.xlsx]Card (Clean)** is the filename of another workbook and worksheet.

```
=SUMIF('[22May UoE Weight Data ECC.xlsx]Card (Clean)'!$N:$N,A3,'[22May UoE Weight Data ECC.xlsx]Card (Clean)'!$E:$E)
```

I would like to be able to put the filename in another cell, then reference that cell in the formula. That way, I'll be able to change the name of the file in that cell to reference another workbook to update my tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) but not sure if it works with a closed file

Comment: Thanks. I saw this suggested elsewhere but couldn't quite work out how to use the function in my formula.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. I managed to work out how to work the INDIRECT function into my formula like this:

=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'["&K3&"]Card (Clean)'!"&"$N:$N"),A3,INDIRECT("'["&K3&"]Card (Clean)'!"&"$E:$E"))

Where K3 contains the filename of the other workbook